# why time limit exceeded in uva 100 problem

Tags: c, time

I don't know what is the matter.. it works great when I run on my pc but when I submit in uva OJ it says time limit exceeded please help

Here is my solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    long int i,j,c,t,k,u,r;
    scanf("%d %d",&i,&j);
    printf("%d %d",i,j);
    r = 0;
    if(i>j){
        t = i;
        i = j;
        j = t;
    }
    for(k = i; k<=j;k++){
        c = 1;
        u = k;
        while(u>1){
            if(u%2 == 0)
                u = u/2;
            else
                u = 3*u+1;
            c++;
            if(c>=r)
                r = c;
        }
    }
    printf (" %d",r);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's the point of online judges: They give you small test sets as examples where the brute-force approach works. When you submit, they throw huge test cases at you so that you have to come up with more efficient code. Asking about solutions here takes all the fun out of it.

Comment: Counting lengths of Collatz chains (see https://projecteuler.net/problem=14)?  So you got two approaches for optimization - first get rid of expensive operations, for example division by two is the same as right shifting one bit (u/2 == (u >> 1)).  The other is to realize that you don't need to explicitly calculate the chain length for every integer.  Suppose we know that if n=10, we have length = 6.  Now if we are dealing with n=13 our chain starts as 13 -> 40 ->20 -> 10.  At this point we can just look up the previously calculated value for 10 and add it to the current length.

Comment: thanks M Oehm you are right

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile. under Ubuntu linux 14.04 with `gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -std=gnu99` .  The compiler outputs 5 warning messages, all on 3 calls to `printf()`  They all say a similar statement: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int' (or `int *`, but argument x has type 'long int' (or 'long int *`) . Suggest correcting the format strings.  a long int is printed via '%ld' rather than '%d'  and a pointer is printed via '%p'

Comment: for ease of understanding and readability by us humans:  1) use variable names that indicate content or usage (or better) both.  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  3) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line

Comment: this line: just before the `return` statement: `printf (" %ld",r);` should be: `printf( " %ld\n", r );`   However, see my answer to a much faster algorithm.  I.E by `fastWrite( r );  putchar_unlocked('\n');`

Comment: the problem statement does not mention needing to read anything.   To make the code really fast (but will result in a much larger .data  1) write your own program, that starts with 1million, and outputs to a file each number sequence.  Then edit that file into sequence[] = { ... where each number is nothing but the offset for the next number in the sequence.  Then when given some number, start at that offset in the sequence and follow the 'links', keeping count of how many links, until '1' is reached.  then it is just strolls through a table (a huge table) to calculate the answer.

Comment: even faster algorithm  Each entry in the sequence could be a count of the number of entries in a sequence starting with that number,  Then the code will be 1) get test values 2) lookup in table the length of each sequence for that starting point, 3) compare the results 4) output the answer.

Comment: i am trying hard but can't solve it anyways just need a little help,, someone improve this code.. it will help me. because I am new c language..

Comment: the idea of the 'challenge' problems is to progressively stretch your C coding capability, especially as regards to clear thinking about a problem and your ability to express that problem in C code.  The comments and answer have given you some ways to speedup I/O and a possible approach to implementing the code algorithm.  Be sure to read the problem again. this is a critical line in the problem statement: *Which starting number, under one million, produces the longest chain?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code, on my ubuntu Linux 14.04 takes about 1 second to run, when invoked via:

```
./untitled > outfile.txt
```

so perhaps this could be useful.

Note: this will have to be modified significantly for the euler problem

Note: the problem says "UNDER" 1 million, but this code starts at 1 million rather than starting at 999999

```
//  Longest Collatz sequence
// Problem 14

/*
 * criteria
 * The following iterative sequence is defined for the set of positive integers:
 *     n → n/2 (n is even)
 *     n → 3n + 1 (n is odd)
 *
 * example:
 * Using the rule above and starting with 13, we generate the following sequence:
 *     13 → 40 → 20 → 10 → 5 → 16 → 8 → 4 → 2 → 1
 * It can be seen that this sequence (starting at 13 and finishing at 1) contains 10 terms.
 * Although it has not been proved yet (Collatz Problem),
 * it is thought that all starting numbers finish at 1.
 *
 * the question:
 * Which starting number, under one million, produces the longest chain?
 *
 * Note:
 * Once the chain starts the terms are allowed to go above one million.
 */

#include <stdio.h>

// prototypes
void fastWrite( size_t a );



int main( void )
{
    #define MAX_START_VALUE (1000000)

    size_t LongestChain = 0;
    size_t LongestStartValue = 0;

    for( size_t i=MAX_START_VALUE; i; i--)
    {
        size_t chainLength = 0;
        size_t result = i;

        // for debug
        char buffer[] = "current start value:";
        for( size_t j=0; buffer[j]; j++) putchar_unlocked( buffer[j] );
        putchar_unlocked( ' ');
        fastWrite( i );
        // end debug

        while( result != 1 )
        {
            chainLength++;

            if( result&1 )
            { // then odd
                result = 3*result +1;
            }

            else
            { // else even
                result >>= 1;
            }

            // for debug
            //./fastWrite( result );
            // end debug
        }
        chainLength++;

        // for debug
        char buffer2[] = "chain length: ";
        for( size_t k=0; buffer2[k]; k++) putchar_unlocked( buffer2[k] );
        fastWrite( chainLength );
        putchar_unlocked( '\n' );
        // end debug

        if ( chainLength > LongestChain )
        {
            LongestChain = chainLength;
            LongestStartValue = i;
        }
    }



    fastWrite( LongestStartValue );
    putchar_unlocked('\n');
    //putchar_unlocked('\n');
} // end function: main


inline void fastWrite(size_t a)
{
    char snum[20];
    //printf( "%s, %lu\n", __func__, a );

    int i=0;
    do
    {
        // 48 is numeric character 0
        snum[i++] = (char)((a%10)+(size_t)48);
        a=a/10;
    }while(a>0);

    i=i-1; // correction for overincrement from prior 'while' loop

    while(i>=0)
    {
        putchar_unlocked(snum[i--]);
    }
    putchar_unlocked('\n');
} // end function: fastWrite
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to be helpful with the time taken:

the following are good ways to speed up the I/O

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fastRead( size_t *a );
void fastWrite( size_t a );

inline void fastRead(size_t *a)
{
    int c=0;
    // note: 32 is space character
    while (c<33) c=getchar_unlocked();

    // initialize result value
    *a=0;

    // punctuation parens, etc are show stoppers
    while (c>47 && c<58)
    {
        *a = (*a)*10 + (size_t)(c-48);
        c=getchar_unlocked();
    }
    //printf( "%s, value: %lu\n", __func__, *a );
} // end function: fastRead


inline void fastWrite(size_t a)
{
    char snum[20];
    //printf( "%s, %lu\n", __func__, a );

    int i=0;
    do
    {
        // 48 is numeric character 0
        snum[i++] = (char)((a%10)+(size_t)48);
        a=a/10;
    }while(a>0);

    i=i-1; // correction for overincrement from prior 'while' loop

    while(i>=0)
    {
        putchar_unlocked(snum[i--]);
    }
    putchar_unlocked('\n');
} // end function: fastWrite
```

and output characters via:

```
putchar_unlocked( char );
```

and always have a final, at end of each test case, the following line:

```
putchar_unlocked( '\n' );
```

to input a string of characters, call the following in a loop until a space or newline is encountered

```
char = getchar_unlocked()
```

and a final hint:  most such problems are easily solved using `size_t` numeric values,  which allows values to 4gig or more. (same as a `unsigned long int`)

For the current problem.  as soon as a chain is calculated, save the chain, perhaps in an array, so you do not have to calculate it again.

Your could pre-calculate the first 'x' chains, say the first 10 for instance, to help with shortening the execution time.

Comment: can you modify my problem? I am new in C.